# Web stack for Single Page Application using Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, single-page-application, web-frontend

**What is the development stack for Landing Page using Vue.js?** - this is my ugly question.
Maybe it's more general question, but I need your help and clarifying with some of my misunderstandings.

Usually, when I need to create Landing Page I use simple `HTML`, `CSS` and `JS` with `Bootstrap`, `HTML Boilerplate` and `jQuery` staff.

But now, I need to create fast and robust, differently animated Landing Page with `e-mail`, `language support`, `notifying` functionalities. Before, for that functionality purposes I used backend support with `python` stack (`Django`). Because, I did not know how to securely use emailing and etc. on frontend. I'm basically back-end developer and these things are dark side for me. But I totally know that these goals can be achieved with frontend stack simply and gracefully. That is why I decided to use beautiful `Vue.js`.

Therefore, I need to clarify for me next things (*don't be critic and angry for my dummy questions, please*):

- **How to secure mailing credentials and my js scripts?**

  Because, I couldn't understand if I can call requests from scripts that available to everyone as js assets from browser. How it is possible to hide that functionality and these scripts with sensible information? I will add to it some `Google Analytics` support and etc.
- **What should I use?**

  Again, general question. From [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) I see, that I can simply use my friendly knowledge of HTTP, CSS and JS. But I search from web and I see that people use `npm`s, `nuxt`s, `webpack`s and etc. All of these `nodejs` and `npm` related staff is the big hole for me. But if it is necessary I will use it. What stack should I use? Just `Vue.js`, `HTML`, `CSS`?
- **How to deploy on production such js related SPA project?**

  I just need simple `vps` server, `nginx` and that is all?

Will be very glad to see some advices from great [experts](https://youtu.be/BKorP55Aqvg), who has experience with that staff :)

Moreover, I will be very happy to see some roadmaps while developing such projects.

P.S.: I know that this kind of questions are not likely for StackOverflow. But anyway I need your help.

Comment: The frontend cannot be secured, no matter how hard you try. You can **never** trust what's going on in the browser.

Comment: I am not an expert about these things either but it sounds like Nuxt would solve a lot of your problems efficiently if you get into it : https://nuxtjs.org/